# How do I implement a nfc reader (ACR122) to an Electron project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nfc

I have downloaded this library (https://github.com/pokusew/nfc-pcsc) and now i'm trying to run an Electron project in it, but is giving me everytime problems when i try to run it as an Electron project. 
So my question is: How can I implement this library on my Electron project and make it work not as node.js

I tried to `npm install --save electron@latest` in the library and change on the json the script `"example": "node -r @babel/register examples/read-write.js"` to `"example": "electron -r @babel/register examples/read-write.js"` also i have tried to uninstall and install, i have done electron-rebuild

```
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w yourmodule",
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
    "example": "electron -r @babel/register examples/read-write.js",
    "example-basic": "node -r @babel/register examples/basic.js",
    "example-from-readme-3": "node -r @babel/register examples/from-readme-3.js",
    "example-led": "node -r @babel/register examples/led.js",
    "example-mifare-classic": "node -r @babel/register examples/mifare-classic.js",
    "example-mifare-desfire": "node -r @babel/register examples/mifare-desfire.js",
    "example-mifare-ultralight-ntag": "node -r @babel/register examples/mifare-ultralight-ntag.js",
    "example-ndef": "node -r @babel/register examples/ndef.js",
    "example-uid-logger": "node -r @babel/register examples/uid-logger.js",
    "example-without-auto": "node -r @babel/register examples/without-auto.js",
    "prepack": "yarn build && yarn test",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test ava test/tests.js --verbose"
  }
```

I'm getting this error when i'm trying to run the app as Electron app (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v6hO.png) and when i do the rebuild i have this error: × Rebuild Failed An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild

Comment: hi, im new to electron and having hardtime implementing how to read nfc card using https://github.com/pokusew/nfc-pcsc. i have search all over but no code example implementation in electron. can u help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electron as of v5.0.0 is using Node.js v12.0.0. This native module (nfc-pcsc) is not building correctly for that version.

Downgrade Electron to v4, rebuild via "electron-rebuild" and it should build properly.

```sh
npm install --save-dev electron@4
```

then

```sh
electron-rebuild
```

Comment: I got the same error but now is the 69 and not the 70: https://i.imgur.com/prnsyxS.png

Comment: Did you use "electron-rebuild"?

Your npm rebuild script should be like this:

`"rebuild": "electron-rebuild"`

What happens when you run this script? Does the build succeed or give an error?

Comment: I got this error: https://i.imgur.com/K7TQPmU.png . I got the same script as you.

Comment: "electron-rebuild" is not recognized. Do you have electron-rebuild installed? if not, run this `npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild` then run `npm run rebuild`

Comment: I have tried so many things and i forgot to install the rebuild now it works, thank you!